# Probability and distribution from actual data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Let's say I have some data from a real world system:

```
data = {0.026666156, 1.27421*^-6, 0.027878597, 0.017035598, 
   0.011036215, 0.038684388, 0.025161479, 0.021353902, 0.027487123, 
   0.021190747, 0.029328752, 0.014554109, 0.040037348, 0.020063044, 
   0.018363514, 0.0116034, 0.02609979, 0.024298555, 0.020568345, 
   0.017299039, 0.005427133, 0.023453297, 0.037443984, 0.031152865, 
   0.020158735, 0.014362383, 0.034687449, 0.01472421, 1.29928*^-6, 
   0.023887209, 0.014531724, 0.03055792, 0.027206875, 0.02227913, 
   0.01618167, 0.032540959, 1.26651*^-6, 0.021810796, 0.038698191, 
   0.014228248, 0.020261827, 0.031292827, 0.01142724, 0.039466342, 
   0.035504951};
```

If I generate histograms for this data it looks like this:

```
Column[{
    Histogram[data, {.005}, "Probability", ImageSize -> Large], 
    Histogram[data, {0.005}, "CDF", ImageSize -> Large]
}]
```

[image: PDF]
[image: CDF]

My question is twofold.

1. Is there a way to "fit" this data with a distribution? Or make a pseudo-distribution with this data?
   I've found `d = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
   DiscretePlot[CDF[d, x], {x, 0, .05, .0001}]`, but is this the best way?
2. How do you programmatically calculate the P50 value from this data? (50% confidence that the value will be realized. y = 0.5 on CDF plot)

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at [`howto/DoStatisticalAnalysis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/DoStatisticalAnalysis.html) (and keep a handy link to the reference). It's very useful.

Comment: @R.M, I'll keep the link handy. And thanks for the quality editing.

Comment: See empirical distribution, introduced by Kolmogorov: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function

Comment: Related: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/267/approximate-a-distribution-function-from-a-finite-sample

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are basically four ways you can do this:

1. Discretely, using [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html), as you suggest in your question
2. Also discretely, but in a bucketed way, using [`HistogramDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramDistribution.html)
3. Smoothly, using [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) or [`KernelMixtureDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KernelMixtureDistribution.html).
4. By fitting an assumed distribution, e.g. by using [`EstimatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html), [`FindDistributionParameters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html) and related commands.

Which you choose depends on  the nature of your data and what you know about it. If you have reason to believe the data are distributed according to some known distribution, choose #4.  Since your data are real-valued, it is likely that it comes from a continuous distribution and so choices #3 or #4 seem most appropriate.

Once you have your estimated distribution, you can calculate the P50 value using [`Quantile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quantile.html).

It is worth noting, though, that particular settings will give different estimates of the quantile. For example there is more than one way to define the kernel used in `SmoothKernelDistribution`. Using the data in your question:

```
Quantile[SmoothKernelDistribution[data ,  Automatic, #], 0.5] & /@
 {"Biweight", "Cosine", "Epanechnikov", "Gaussian", 
  "Rectangular", "SemiCircle", "Triangular", "Triweight"}

{0.0222671, 0.0223012, 0.0223522, 0.0223533, 0.0223458, 0.0223374,  0.0222653, 0.0222342}
```

Of course, in some fields, four decimal places is close enough.

Comment: "...using `Quantile[]`." - or `InverseCDF[]`.

Comment: @Verbeia, Thanks for the answer. And yes, I usually work on stuff a mile or more underground, 4 decimals is plenty.

Comment: @kale - you are most welcome. I count my own field (economics) as one where four significant figures is plenty. Indeed, more than three or four usually invites mockery and (justified) jibes of providing false precision.

Comment: @Verbeia, in addition to `SmoothKernelDistribution`, `Quantile` itself has a 4-dimensional parameter space (so much for "non-parameteric") that is not well-documented. Certain points in this parameter space are associated with named methods, but it's difficult to relate them or interpolated values.